# How do you enable view source in ie8 when it gets magically diabled

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

I have multiple computers that all seem to have View Source disabled from the content menu when you right click on a web page. Now I know it's not that the web page is some how disabling it, I'm pretty sure thats not even possible. But alas I have at least 3 machines in my office (not on AD) that have this problem. I have also worked on clients computers that have this same issue. It's down right maddening!

I tried to Google for it, but it just shows [results](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum10/3362.htm) from the dawn of IE6 in all of it's "glory" with a bug where if the cache was full it would be disabled. But this is not the case in IE8.

Any body have a clue why this is happening, or a fix for it? Maybe a reg setting?

**Update:**
So I got a little closer to solving it, but there was still an issue on one computer where it allowed it not is HTTP, but not in HTTPS. One other computer works correctly in both. I Found these two keys missing in the registry:

```
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor]
```

Comment: You could probably use `Tools->Developer Tools` and choose script tab to get the complete source code in IE8.

Comment: Thats more of a quick and dirty workaround, and not so much a fix. I'm looking for an actual fix here for both HTTP and HTTPS. Plus while I did not mention it I have the same issue in IE7 clients. Though I am pushing people into IE8 as much as possible. So the dev toolbar is not a default option in IE7.

Comment: Is it worth the trouble?? Why not FF and Firebug ?

Comment: App is locked in on IE, so I'm not able to do it with FF. Plus if it were a clients computer, I'm sure they would not want me installing additional apps. Though I do love me some Firebug thats for sure. Oh and yes, it's worth the trouble. Even beyond being locked into IE on this LOB app

Comment: Just today I ran into that problem on a single user PC (Windows XP, IE8, part of an AD) and seeking a solution. Developer Tools -> View -> Source -> Original works. I don't have the above mentioned registry entries. I'd like to solve this so view source works as expected again. I also disabled a lot of add-ons, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

is it happening for https sites? if so try tools - Internet Options - Advance
go to security tab and check-off Do not save encrypted pages to disk.

Try Bing search insted of google, it gives more proper search result (atleast for this.)

Comment: Still a valid solution for IE11. Not sure who turned this off on my computer, it magically changed sometime this week.

And google has gotten much worse in the intervening six years

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Oracle i-store (on IE8) and following solution can be used as a workaround on secure (https) pages:

once the secure page is displayed, go to: Tools-->Developer tools --> View tab --> Source --> original