# How to fix Internet Explorer 8 source view when it doesn't work anymore?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you enable view source in ie8 when it gets magically diabled](https://superuser.com/questions/115876/how-do-you-enable-view-source-in-ie8-when-it-gets-magically-diabled)

Environment: Windows XP Pro, part of a Domain, restricted User accounts, all Windows Updates / Service Packs loaded, Internet Explorer 8 . Other uses with the same rights don't have the problems (on other PCs)

Symptom: right-click on any page (be it `HTTP` or `HTTPS`) and choosing `view source` yields *no action at all*

Same/similar questions: [How do you enable view source in ie8 when it gets magically disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/115876/how-do-you-enable-view-source-in-ie8-when-it-gets-magically-diabled)

Workaround found so far: use [`Tools -> Developer Tools -> View -> Source -> original`](https://superuser.com/questions/115876/how-do-you-enable-view-source-in-ie8-when-it-gets-magically-diabled/139721#139721)

Other proposed solution from the other question which didn't work or didn't make sense:

- Clearing the cache, browser history, everything; i.e. make room for `view-source` to work: no change
- Prepend the URL with `view-source:`: it's not supported in IE8 anymore
- Restore missing registry keys: the keys `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor` and `HKCM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor`; **but**: neither of those keys are present on any other machine were `view source` *is* working

Comment: the other question hasn't been solved, so let's keep answers together there.  closing as duplicate.

Comment: @Quack Too bad, I hoped to get attention to it because the other question obviously had no activity anymore. But it's understandable, thanks.